# GitHub Actions logs not appearing when using environment

Tags: github-actions

I have noticed in GitHub Actions, when I have a `environment: prod` set, that the logs do not appear:

```
password_rotate:
  environment: prod
  name: password_rotate
  runs-on: [ self-hosted ]
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: password_rotate
      id: prod
      uses: ./.github/actions/rotate
```

There should be logs in here called `password_rotate`:

[image]

When I remove `environment: prod`, the logs appear as expected.

How can I use `environment: prod` and see the logs in GitHub Actions?

Comment: You're looking at a completed job and the logs for the steps are collapsed when you check a completed job. Did you try to expand these steps?

Comment: Yep, there is nothing related to what should be in `password_rotate`; when I remove `environment: prod`, I see the `password_rotate` logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution. This may be a bug with GitHub Actions.

`environment: prod` can't match with the id below that `id: prod`

So to fix this, you either need to update `environment` or `id` to be unique from each other, otherwise the logs do not appear.

What I ended up doing was re-naming `id` to `id: rotateprod`

```
password_rotate:
  environment: prod
  name: password_rotate
  runs-on: [ self-hosted ]
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: password_rotate
      id: rotateprod
      uses: ./.github/actions/rotate
```